# How do you indicate that an action is done after a character says something in a script?

Tags: formatting, script

[image]

How do you indicate that an action is done after a character says something in a script? The action is right after the scene heading, but what happens when an action is done after a character says something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either add another heading, as you did in the Action line, or as a [parenthetical](https://www.movieoutline.com/articles/a-glossary-of-screenwriting-terms-and-filmmaking-definitions.html) (image from link):[image]